# JQuery - How can i add two events on the same function

Tags: jquery

I'm new at jQuery and i want to know how can i add two events at the same function.

I already have a function, that calls what i want if the person answering the from, clicks "tab", but i want to do the same thing when the person clicks with the mouse in another field.

How can i do that?

I have my little script here

```
$("#tags").blur(function(){
    if ($(".tags").val() == ""){
        $("#checktags").html('Right');
    } else {
       $("#checktags").html('Wrong');
    }
});
```

Comment: Trigger it; `$("#tags").trigger("blur")`

Comment: Add it to the selector `$("#tags, #other_element").blur(...`

Answer (score 0):

give all the elements you want to be clicked on a class `.to-be-clicked`

Then

```
$(".to-be-clicked").blur(function(){
    if ($(".tags").val() == ""){
        $("#checktags").html('Right');
    } else {
       $("#checktags").html('Wrong');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this code is simplethis code is simple, in the selector you can reference to a class `$(".input")` or to an id `$("#input")`. The letter "e" in the `function(e)` is a variable that can be used according to your needs, you can see the data contained in the console browser by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>

```js
 $("#input").on('blur',function(e){
        console.log(e);
  if($(this).val()!=''){
   alert($(this).val());
  }else{
   alert('empty field');
  }
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="input" id="input" value="" placeholder="input">
```